# Closest Point on a Sphere to Another Point

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

Given a sphere $S(c,r)$, $c$ being the center point $(x,y,z)$ and $r$ being the radius, there is a point $p(x', y', z')$ which is either inside or outside $S$.
I want to find the point $q$ such that $q$ is on $S$ and $|pq|$ is minimum. Where $|pq|$ denotes the Euclidean distance between $p$ and $q$.

I tried to create a ray that starts from $c$ and passes through $p$ and find the intersection of the ray with the sphere.

However, since I'm implementing a code for this problem, I could not get over it with step by step. Could you please help me?

Comment: I guess the easiest would be to move the entire problem to $c=(0,0,0)$, then transform the point p to spherical coordinates, set $r=1$ and move the point you found back to the original $c$. There must be quicker methods for this, but this shouldn't be hard to implement anyway.

Comment: Maybe it's overkill, but this sounds exactly like Lagrange multipliers. You want to minimize $|pq|$ with the constraint that $q$ must be on $S$. I would solve it on paper using lagrange multipliers and then write a code.

Comment: @OriaGruber This is really an overkill. I don't know how to model the problem with Lagrange multipliers. Even if I did, it is pretty hard for me to implement it. I got 4 hours to do this.

Comment: Then what HSN suggested would also work. It is basically what you proposed, finding the intersection of the ray with the sphere. Suppose that $c=(x,y,z)$. create a new $c_1=(0,0,0)$. transform $p$ to polar coordinate and set $r=1$ to get a point on this new circle, lets say this point is $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$. The answer you need is $(\alpha+x,\beta+y,\gamma+z)$

Comment: Or just use similarity of triangles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Known: $r, C=\langle x_c, y_c, z_c\rangle, P=\langle x_p, y_p, z_p\rangle$

Unknown: $Q=\langle \color{blue}{x_q, y_q, z_q}\rangle: Q\in S(C, r)\bigwedge \overline{CQ} \parallel \overline{CP}$

Use the similarity of triangles to assert the equivalence of the following ratios:
$$\begin{align} \frac{|CP|}{|CQ|} & =\frac{\sqrt{(x_p-x_c)^2+(y_p-y_c)^2+(z_p-z_c)^2}}{r}\\ ~ & =\frac{x_p-x_c}{\color{blue}{x_q}-x_c}\\ ~ & =\frac{y_p-y_c}{\color{blue}{y_q}-y_c}\\ ~ & =\frac{z_p-z_c}{\color{blue}{z_q}-z_c} \\ \therefore \color{blue}{x_q} & = x_c +\frac{ r(x_p-x_c)}{\sqrt{(x_p-x_c)^2+(y_p-y_c)^2+(z_p-z_c)^2}} \\ \color{blue}{y_q} & = y_c +\frac{ r(y_p-y_c)}{\sqrt{(x_p-x_c)^2+(y_p-y_c)^2+(z_p-z_c)^2}} \\ \color{blue}{z_q} & = z_c +\frac{ r(z_p-z_c)}{\sqrt{(x_p-x_c)^2+(y_p-y_c)^2+(z_p-z_c)^2}} \end{align}$$

Answer (score 4):

Surely it's just
$$\mathbf c + \frac{r}{|\mathbf p-\mathbf c|}(\mathbf p-\mathbf c),
$$
right?

Comment: Yes.  That's the short hand notation.

Comment: what are $|p-c|$ and $(p-c)$. I think the first one is the magnitude of the difference and the second one is difference

Comment: @cagirici: That's correct